# Reorder the rows of a table according to the numbers of similar cells in a specific column using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

| D | S |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 1 |

in which the code of symptoms(S) of three diseases(D) are shown. I want to rearrange this table (D-S) such that the diseases with more symptoms come up i.e. order it by decreasing the numbers of symptoms as below:

| D | S |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 |

Can anyone help me to write a SQL code for it in SQL server?

I had tried to do this as the following but this doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    select D, Count(S) cnt
    from  [D-S]
    group by D  
)  Q
order by Q.cnt desc
```

Comment: The rows in a table have no order. You can write a query against the table that will return results in a specific order. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
    D,
    S
from
    D-S
order by
    count(*) over(partition by D) desc, 
    D, 
    S;
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Two easy ways to approach this:

```
--==== Sample Data
DECLARE @t TABLE (D INT, S INT);
INSERT  @t VALUES(2,1),(2,3),(4,2),(4,3),(4,5),(6,1);

--==== Using Window Function
SELECT  t.D, t.S
FROM    (SELECT t.*, Rnk = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.D) FROM  @t AS t) AS t
ORDER BY t.Rnk DESC;

--==== Using standard GROUP BY
SELECT t.*
FROM  @t AS t
JOIN
(
  SELECT t2.D, Cnt = COUNT(*)
  FROM     @t AS t2
  GROUP BY t2.D
) AS t2 ON t.D = t2.D
ORDER BY t2.Cnt DESC;
```

**Results:**

```
D           S
----------- -----------
4           2
4           3
4           5
2           1
2           3
6           1
```

Comment: Thanks @Alan. 1. Can I use your Windows function in SQL server? 
2. I have made the table using a query on another table M:
Select ... from M ....
 How can I apply your code on this query? Should I first save my table then use your code or I can mix them with each other?